# Accelerating matplotlib figure update

Tags: python, python-2.7, canvas, matplotlib, figure

I am using Python 2.7.9 with matplotlib to display live data taken from a microcontroller in a FigureCanvasTKAgg. The figure itself must always display the last 100 points and resize the Y axis to display and 'snug fit' all points. X axis is updated as well to show the correct time stamp of each point.

This figure update involves redrawing all artists (as all of them change) at every figure update which is called using an `after` method every 100ms. I am using `line.set_data(x,y)` to update the actual data points and the required methods for updating the Y and X axes limits, followed by `canvas.draw()`. This works OK, at almost 5fps(the drawing itself takes ~100ms).

My question is: is there a faster way of doing this? From what I understand the `draw` method redraws the whole canvas including the subplots. Is there a way to update only the lines displayed and the splines and hence increase the fps?

I tried implementing a solution using `ax.draw_artist(lines)` and the rest, however this adds new artists and do not delete the previous ones.